# Plot overwriting in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I'm using FeniCS to solve a PDE at different time-steps which I then store into various lists and plot in python using matplotlib. I'm having problems trying to create and save multiple (three) plots in a loop. I can only manage to save one plot without them overwriting. Neglecting necessary details, my code looks like this

```
for n in range(num_steps):

    #Update current time
    t += dt
    

    #Solve
    solve(a_form == L_form, u)
    
    #Store times
    t_vals.append(t)

    #Solve PDE, gives solution u
    solve(u)

    #Create empty lists
    u_vals_x = []
    u_vals_y = []
    u_vals_z = []

    #Set constant
    xyz_fixed_density = 1000
    #Store u values varying x, y and z held equal to 1
    for n in  np.linspace(x0,x1,xyz_fixed_density):
     u_vals_x.append(u(n,1,1))

     #Store u values varying y, x and z held equal to 1
    for n in  np.linspace(y0,y1,xyz_fixed_density):
     u_vals_y.append(u(1,n,1))


     #Store u values varying z, x and y held equal to 1
    for n in  np.linspace(z0,z1,xyz_fixed_density):
     u_vals_z.append(u(1,1,n))
    
    #First plot
    plt.scatter(np.linspace(x0,x1,xyz_fixed_density),u_vals_x,s=1)
    plt.legend(t_vals)
    plt.xlabel('$x$')
    plt.ylabel('$u(t,x,1,1)$')
    plt.savefig('u_vs_x.png')
    
    #Second plot
    plt.scatter(np.linspace(y0,y1,xyz_fixed_density),u_vals_y,s=1)
    plt.legend(t_vals)
    plt.xlabel('$y$')
    plt.ylabel('$u(t,1,y,1)$')
    plt.savefig('u_vs_y.png')
    
    #Third plot
    plt.scatter(np.linspace(z0,z1,xyz_fixed_density),u_vals_z,s=1)
    plt.legend(t_vals)
    plt.xlabel('$z$')
    plt.ylabel('$u(t,1,1,z)$')
    plt.savefig('u_vs_z.png')
```

It's probably a simple fix but I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a loop from 0 to `num_steps` and in each iteration of the loop you’re saving three plots to the same three filenames. Is that the issue? You want to vary the filenames?

Comment: Hi, no the problem is that when I run the code all three images are the same, like the  plots are being overwritten. I tried plt.clf() after each plot but this didn't work.

Comment: If I comment out two of the three plots and run the code, it works fine. But doing this three times isn't good.

Comment: Did you try `plt.figure()`? — However, it would generally be better to actually generate new plot objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current iteration (`n`) as part of the filenames; e.g. replace

```
plt.savefig('u_vs_x.png')
```

with

```
plt.savefig(f'u_vs_x_{n}.png')
```

This uses the f-string syntax to format the code. If you’re using an older Python version which does not support f-strings yet, use `format` explicitly:

```
plt.savefig('u_vs_x_{}.png'.format(n))
```

You’ll also need to create a *new plot* each time, e.g. via

```
plt.figure()
```

Comment: Hi, this is an improvement. The three plots are different but it's only plotting one curve in each plot, namely the first "l" value.